# How to implement Content Security Policy with WordPress Nonces in PHP using PHP header-method?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, content-security-policy, nonce

Currently I am trying to implement a Content Security Policy on a WordPress Landing page. I am using the following header-method in PHP to implement a Content Security Policy:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-RandomSeq' 'nonce-hzthedtrh5' 'nonce-hjjftzrf56zf'  ... ")
```

And I am attempting to use [WordPress Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to create random nonces for a inline Javascript code

```
<?php
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'my-nonce' ); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" nonce="<?php echo $nonce; ?>">
  // some javascript code
</script>
```

This example works when I specifiy the nonce with a string like "435234JHHJK2", but when I try to put a variable in the header like this:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-".$nonce."' 'nonce-hzthedtrh5' 'nonce-hjjftzrf56zf'  ... ")
```

The random nonce, created by wp-nonce is not recognized and the given script won't be executed.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

PHP does not accept variables in single quotes liike in `'noce-".$nonce."'`
Solution is to save the whole in CSP information in an external string variable:

```
$csp = "Content-Security-Policy: script-src  'nonce-".$nonce1."' 'nonce-".$nonce2."'...";
```

and to include this variable into the PHP header method:

```
header( "{$csp}");
```